# EC2 and login logging

Tags: logging, ssh, monitoring, amazon-ec2

I have set up several EC2 instances and intend to give multiple users access to them via SSH. Is there any file on the server that monitors who logs in and when?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Max.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the auth log Daniel mentioned, assuming you're using Linux on your EC2 instance (which is likely), see:

- the *last*(1) command, which reads */var/log/utmp*
- the *utmp*(5) file formats and the *getutent()* C function.

Answer (score 19):

None of the suggested answers here (except the `last` command) applied on Amazon Linux. I found SSH attempts and logins, as well as privilege escalations, in `/var/log/secure`.

Comment: For AWS Linux the SSH / SSHd login logging is indeed in /var/log/secure.

Answer (score 5):

SSH logins are usually logged automatically in `/var/log/auth.log`. You can grep this file to check who logged in and when.

If you do not have an `auth.log`, you may need to check `/etc/syslog.conf` and make sure you have the following line: `auth.* /var/log/auth`.

Comment: There is no auth.log and even I dont have syslog.conf file inside etc directory . What could be the reason ?

Comment: This totally "works", and I could stream this file to CloudWatch. But it's worth noting that (at least for me), if you're on an EC2 instance, you will get *absolutely barraged* with random failed SSH login attempts from bots in China, and my logs were completely flooded. I had to shut it off, and I'm working on another solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is what helped me:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check out SSHLog: https://github.com/sshlog/agent/

It's a daemon that monitors SSH logins as well as user activity.  The access info can be sent to a remote syslog server, Slack, a statsd server, or local log files.